# Is there any free javascript formatter for Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, format, indentation

JSEclipse doesn't support `Ctrl+Shift+F` Format command.
Is there any plugin that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here : [Eclipse JavaScript Formatter](http://www.coderanch.com/t/105371/vc/Eclipse-JavaScript-formatter)

> You need to configure your keys under
>   Eclipse preferences window.
>
> In preferences window, Under General,
>   check the Keys option.

Comment: This is already configured by default. The problem is that this feature isn't implemented. So it does nothing.

Comment: @Jader : Did you try NX Format, a js code formatter, as per specified in the thread post ?